# Spring Autowiring of Map Behavior

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

My question is regarding how Spring injects a bean of type `java.util.Map` into a class via `@Autowired`.  Specifically, the behavior that I'm seeing is that the value of the autowired bean in the class is actually a Map that contains one key-value pair, where the key is the name of the bean, and the value is the map that I intended to inject.  I expected Spring to have injected the map directly.

Here is the class in which I autowire the bean:

```
@Component
public class SpringMapParent {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("theMap")
    private Map<String, Object> theMap;

    ...
}
```

I defined `theMap` in my Spring Java configuration like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class SpringMapConfiguration {

    @Bean("theMap")
    public Map<String, Object> getTheMap() {
        Map<String, Object> theMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        return theMap;
    }

    ...
}
```

Note that the map size is 0.

My unit test to test this injection fails:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringMapConfiguration.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SpringMapIT {

    @Autowired
    private SpringMapParent springMapParent;

    @Test
    public void testSpringMapParentAutowiredCorrectly() {
        Map<String, Object> theMap = springMapParent.getTheMap();
        assertEquals(0, theMap.size());
    }
}
```

The size of the `theMap` is actually 1.  The one entry is:

```
{theMap={}}
```

Why is this?  And how do I actually inject the map defined in the bean directly into the `theMap` field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@Autowired` on `Map` is processing by particular way. [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation) says:

> Even typed Maps can be autowired as long as the expected key type is String. The Map values will contain all beans of the expected type, and the keys will contain the corresponding bean names

Also another [section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) of documentation says:

> For beans that are themselves defined as a collection/map or array type, `@Resource` is a fine solution, referring to the specific collection or array bean by unique name. That said, as of 4.3, collection/map and array types can be matched through Spring’s `@Autowired` type matching algorithm as well, as long as the element type information is preserved in `@Bean` return type signatures or collection inheritance hierarchies. In this case, qualifier values can be used to select among same-typed collections, as outlined in the previous paragraph.

So, you can inject `Map` bean next way:

```
@Component
public class SpringMapParent {
    @Resource
    @Qualifier("theMap")
    private Map<String, Object> theMap;

    ...
}
```